# plot pandas period_range with matplotlib - set freq of axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I got a pandas DataFrame with values for time spans with variable lenths. I want to plot a horizontal line for the value of each timespan with the length of the timespan. Therfore, I converted the timespan to an PeriodIndex by

```
ax0=fig.add_axes([.16,.2,0.8,.7])
ax0.plot_date(data['periodIndex'], data['value'])
```

which produces:

```
TypeError: Axis must have `freq` set to convert to Periods
```

so my Question is how to set the frequency of my xaxis

Thanks a lot for your help

Axel

**UPDATE**

this is part of the pandas dataFrame I want to plot

```
     start        stop          A           B          C
ID                                                                    
1    2015-08-17   2015-08-25    -5.684246  -34.759047  10.714920   
2    2015-08-25   2015-09-02   -10.850721  -78.443556   8.362215   
3    2015-09-02   2015-09-15    -7.139351  -47.814199   9.300612   
4    2015-09-15   2015-09-21    -7.822367  -56.895241   5.683696   
5    2015-09-21   2015-09-29    -6.491543  -42.947744   8.984596   
6    2015-09-29   2015-10-05    -9.897980  -67.985256  11.198583
```

I solved the problem and now it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB1mI.png)
by the following code

```
firstDate=df.ix[df.index[0]]['start']

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(9*1.5,6*1.5))
ax0=fig.add_axes([.15,.2,0.75,.7])

ax0.set_xticks(df['start_abs'])
ax0.set_xticklabels([i.date() for i in df['start']], rotation='vertical')

B=ax0.twinx()
B.set_ylim(-200,0)

for _index, _series in df.iterrows():
    start=_series['start']
    stop=_series['stop']   
    df.ix[_index, 'start_abs']=(start-firstDate).days
    df.ix[_index, 'width_abs']=(stop-start).days
    df.ix[_index, 'stop_abs']=(stop-firstDate).days

    line_A=ax0.hlines(y=df.ix[_index,'A'], xmin=df.ix[_index, 'start_abs'], xmax=df.ix[_index, 'stop_abs'], colors='r')
    line_A.set_linewidths(3)
    text_A=ax0.text(df.ix[_index, 'start_abs'], df.ix[_index,'A'], '{a:4.2f}'.format(a=df.ix[_index,'A']), fontsize=8, color='r')

    line_B=B.hlines(y=df.ix[_index,'B'], xmin=df.ix[_index,'start_abs'], xmax=df.ix[_index,'stop_abs'], colors='k')
    line_B.set_linewidths(3)
    text_B=B.text(df.ix[_index,'start_abs'], df.ix[_index,'B'], '{a:4.2f}'.format(a=df.ix[_index,'B']), fontsize=8, color='k')

plt.show()
```

Comment: please provide the `data`

Comment: Sorry but if you want help, you have to rephrase your question and provide an example with some row of data. The example provided is not clear since you talk about period index conversion and the code does not show this conversion for e.g. `df['date'].dt.to_period('H')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I constructed data to demonstrate what I believe was your question.

If you fill in a dataframe with data for only a specific range of the index and then plot it, it will only generate a line for when that data was not null.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ts = pd.date_range(end='2016-03-31', periods=250, freq='D')

np.random.seed([3,1415])
ranges = pd.DataFrame((np.random.choice(xrange(100), (2, 10)) +
                       np.array([[0], [150]])),
                      columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'))

df = pd.DataFrame(index=ts)
count = 1
for i, c in ranges.iteritems():
    s, e = c
    df.loc[ts[s]:ts[e], i] = count
    count += 1

df.plot()
```

[image]