# Set custom date ytick labels in both y-axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, timestamp, yaxis

Motivated by the [answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37712201/7823097), I'm looking to show a very similar plot, with the starting date at the left y-axis and the end date at the right y-axis, for each line.

So far I tried to save both start dates and end dates in a list and I used `twinx()` and `set_yticks()`, but that did not work. The code below plots the same plot in the link (barring the legend), but it does not modify the y-axes.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

ts = pd.date_range(end='2016-03-31', periods=250, freq='D')
np.random.seed([3, 1415])
a = np.random.choice(range(100), size=(2,10))
ranges = pd.DataFrame((a + np.array([[0], [150]])), columns=list('abcdefghij'))

df = pd.DataFrame(index=ts)
count = len(ranges.columns)
left_axis = []
right_axis = []
for colname, column in ranges.iteritems():
    start_, end_ = column
    df.loc[ts[start_] : ts[end_], colname] = count
    left_axis.append(ts[start_])
    right_axis.append(ts[end_])
    count -= 1

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(df)
ax1.set_yticks(range(10, 0, -1), left_axis)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_yticks(range(10, 0, -1), right_axis)
plt.legend([])
plt.show()
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

```
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
```

also, to make sure the ticks on the right match the ticks on the left, you have to adjust the `ylim` so they're the same on both axes

```
(...)
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(df)
ax1.set_yticks(range(10, 0, -1))
ax1.set_yticklabels(left_axis)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_yticks(range(10, 0, -1))
ax2.set_yticklabels(right_axis)
ax2.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
plt.legend([])
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]